# Using WinSCP .NET assembly on Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have deployed my application based on WinSCP .NET assembly in Linux.
I'm getting this error:

> WinSCP.SessionLocalException: The winscp.exe executable was not found at the location of the assembly WinSCPnet

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = _sftpConfig["Host"],
    UserName = _sftpConfig["UserName"],
    Password = _sftpConfig["Password"],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP .NET assembly is a wrapper around `WinSCP.exe` scripting interface.

WinSCP is a Windows application. It does not run on Linux on its own. Consequently, the assembly is not really intended to be used on Linux. Quoting [WinSCP .NET assembly documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#purpose):

> The library is primarily intended for advanced automation tasks **on Microsoft Windows** that require conditional processing, loops or other control structures for which the basic scripting interface is too limited.

---

On the other hand, standalone [WinSCP works under Linux using Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1285) without any problem. And there's .NET Core build of the .NET assembly. So it is quite likely that it is possible, but I haven't seen it done yet.